# Javascript Animation Not Working

Tags: javascript, html, animation, syntax

I have a JS animation that is supposed to move images inside of a div called "reel" down or up. There are two arrows with href="javascript:reelUp" or "reelDown", depending on the arrow. For some reason when I click the arrow it throws a syntax error saying that it expected an expression but got end of script. No idea what is wrong--I pulled this straight from a tutorial that works.

Just updated the code after taking in a new suggestions. Its still not working, so I included my (messy) CSS. Any help would really be appreciated! I have no idea what the issue is!

```
<!doctype html>

<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Tales of the Hartland: Homepage</title>

<style type="text/css">

/* ID DEFINITIONS */

#reelHolder {
    height: 750px;
    width: 800px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    position: relative;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-400px;
}

#arrowDown {
    position:relative;
    left:105%;
    top0%;
}

#arrowUp {

}


/*CLASS DEFINITIONS */

.banner {
    position: relative;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-600px;
}

    .arrow {
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
}

.reeler {
    width:600px;
    height:300px;
    position: relative;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-300px;
    margin-top:50px;
}

.break {
    height:0px;
}

.bigBreak {
    height:50px;
}

</style>


<script>
//REEL UP
function reelUp(elem) {

elem = document.getElementById(elem);

var down = 0

function frame() {

    down++

    elem.style.top = down + 'px'

    if (down == 100)
        clearInterval(id)
}

var id = setInterval(frame, 10) // draw every 10ms

}

//REEL DOWN
function reelDown(elem) {

elem = document.getElementById(elem);

var down = 0

function frame() {

down++

    elem.style.top = -1 * down + 'px'

    if (down == 100)
        clearInterval(id)
}

var id = setInterval(frame, 10) // draw every 10ms

}
</script>

</head>

<body>

  <img src="Banner.png" width="1200" height="150" alt="" class="banner"/>


  <div id="reelHolder" class="centerDiv">

    <div id="reel">
        <img src="reel1.png" class="reeler" id="reel1"/>
        <div class="break"></div>
        <img src="reel2.png" class="reeler" id="reel2"/>
    </div>

    <a id="arrowUp" class="arrow" href="javascript:reelUp('reel');">
        <img src="arrowUp.png" alt=""/>
    </a>

    <a id="arrowDown" class="arrow" href="javascript:reelDown('reel');">
        <img src="arrowDown.png" alt=""/>
    </a>

  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

The tutorial code this is based on is available at: http://javascript.info/files/tutorial//browser/animation/move.html

Comment: Just use semicolons.

Comment: I added semicolons after each appropriate line just now. Still throwing the same error.

Comment: have you tried adding semicolons at the end of your href attributes?

Comment: From what I can see, you are creating a function inside other function. Try to separrate both of your function. EX: "frame" is inside function "reelDown". Close your braket befor creating "frame". If you still want to create it this way, please use this.frame = function(){ put your code here} and then call this function. But you will need to create one instence of this pseudo class.

Comment: I added semicolons at the end of the hrefs and got the same error. I then made the functions seprate and still got the error. I'm going to post full code I think

Comment: @SeargentGen - Edit your question and at least put semicolons and correct tabbing in there.

Comment: I added the semicolons in and threw in a link to the tutorial code i am trying to modify.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with functions within functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of the error you're seeing is that you're using double quotes inside your `href` attribute, which is confusing the parser.  See the problem?

```
href="javascript:reelUp("reel")"
```

The most convenient way to get around that is to use single quotes.

```
href="javascript:reelUp('reel')"
```

Do the same for your down arrow as well.

Once you do this, you will still encounter another error, because the `elem` that you're passing to `reelUp()` and `reelDown()` is a string, so this line from `reelUp()`, as well as the corresponding one from `reelDown()`, will fail:

```
elem.style.top = down + 'px';
```

Since `elem` is a string, not an element, your browser will complain.  To fix this, add this:

```
elem = document.getElementById(elem);
```

to the beginning of `reelUp()` and `reelDown()`.  That'll look up the actual element with that ID.

After making these changes, your code works enough that stuff starts moving when you click the arrows.  I'm not sure that it necessarily moves the way you want it to, but this will get you to the point where you can debug that.

**Edit**: In order to be able to see the animation, the element `<div id="reel">` needs a CSS change.  As it is, when you're setting the reel's `top` property, it's being ignored because that alone isn't enough for the browser to know where you want the reel to go.  You also have to set the `position` property.

I don't know exactly what you want, but if you set `position` to `relative`, then that will cause the `top` property to shift the reel up or down relative to its default position.  That's what I did when I was testing my answer.

So add this to your CSS:

```
#reel {
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Great!! Thanks so much for that, I really appreciate it!!! Will try that out as soon as I have a chance.

Comment: Made those changes and, sadly, it is still not working, No errors this time though. Really stumped. Going to report current code

Comment: OK, what happened is that when I was answering your question, I added some CSS to get it to work.  I assumed you already had that CSS and just hadn't included it in your question.

Comment: Great, thanks! It moves now, but I can only hit that button once. After I click it once the link seems to stop responding to future clicks. Any ideas?

Comment: What happened for me was that the `reel` was covering up the arrows, but since it had a transparent background it didn't look like anything was covered up. That's probably what happened to you.  To fix that, you can give the arrows a higher z-index so that they'll be on top of the reel.  You'll also have to set a `position` on them for the z-index to take effect.

Comment: Thanks! I'm actually now having a new problem. If I try to click the button a second time it throws an error parsing 'top'. All I did was move the arrows and add in     "var curLoc = elem.style.top;" and then have curLoc added to the movement piece (so that it wouldn't reset to original position). Any ideas?

Comment: @SeargentGen It probably has something to do with the fact that `top` is a string with the 'px' unit at the end.  It might be best to ask a new question, though.